# Simplest way to find a single csv file using pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I want to read the one and only `csv` file in subfolder `foo`, using `pahtlib`, without having to specify the name explicitly. This way, the code still works if the filename changes, but the precondition that there is one and only one `csv` file in `foo` is still valid.

Right now I do

```
from pathlib import Path

foo_dir = Path.cwd() / 'foo'
for file in foo_dir.glob('*'):
    if file.is_file() & (file.suffix = '.csv'):
        csv_file = file
        break
```

which is...eh, it works, but it's a bit wordy. Is there anything simpler I could do, without sacrificing readability?

PS how can I modify the above code so that in case there's no `csv` file in `foo`, it throws an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python). Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669828/6045800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pathlib.Path.glob` is a generator that yields `pathlib.Path` objects, so you can invoke `next` on it to consume just the first path-object from the generator. You can supply an optional argument to `next` to prevent a `StopIteration` exception from being thrown when no CSV file is present (in this case, `next` returns `None`).

```
from pathlib import Path

if (path := next(Path("dir/to/file").glob("*.csv"), None)) is None:
    print("No .csv file present!")
else:
    print(path)
```

---

OR

```
from pathlib import Path

try:
    path = next(Path("dir/to/file").glob("*.csv"))
except StopIteration:
    raise RuntimeError("No .csv file present!")
```

Comment: oooo I like this - could you please also add the `try-except` alternative? ? I guess something like `try:
    csv_file = next(foo_dir.glob('*.csv'))
except StopIteration:
    raise RuntimeError('No csv file found')`

Comment: @DeltaIV Right, that is the alternative. I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this

```py
from glob import glob

try:
    csv_file = glob('foo/*.csv')[0]
except IndexError:
    raise RuntimeError('No csv file found')
```